# Playing sound on a Thread by a button click but not able to stop it from main thread by another button

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am just trying to play a .wav sound by a button click, by using .Net 4.0 - Task.Factory for selected number of times, it is playing fine, but a moment I want to stop this sound quickly through other button, I can say Stop button, but it is not stopping the sound quickly, it stop only after complete play... below is my code...

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void btnStartPlaying_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();                       
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            int playTimes = 3;

            var compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Playing(playTimes);

            }, tokenSource.Token);
            tasks.Add(compute);

            var displayResults = compute.ContinueWith(resultTask =>                                     
                                                        Environment.NewLine,
                                                        CancellationToken.None,
                                                        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                                                    ui);
            var displayCancelledTasks = compute.ContinueWith(resultTask =>                                               
                                                                Environment.NewLine,
                                                                CancellationToken.None,
                                                                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled, ui);            
            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(),
                result =>
                {

                }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, ui);
}


private void btnStopPlaying_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      tokenSource.Cancel();            
}

public void Playing(int times)
{
     try
     {
      using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("mySoundFile.wav"))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
                    {
                        tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        player.PlaySync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stopped!!!!!");
            }
}
```

Comment: If you call it from the same thread, are you able to stop it? My first guess would be that the SoundPlayer starts its own thread under the hood and stopping the thread that launched it wouldn't do a thing. Can you tell the player to stop instead of trying to stop the thread?

Comment: You'll need to call the Stop() method on another thread.  Also set a flag so you know that PlaySync() completed because you stopped it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to stop the playback immediately.But stopping the file from playing it repeatedly.

Imagine you have cancelled the task when the code has already started executing `player.PlaySync();`.There is no way for the app to know the cancellation has been requested.
Its only during the next iteration the task cancellation exception is thrown.

Also Task class emphasises on cooperative cancellation,which means you dont want the sound to stop playing abruptly.